# Logging from one docker container to another

Tags: jenkins, docker

I think I am missing something linking docker containers.
I have 2 containers, 1 running Jenkins and 1 running elk stack.

From the host I can easily get logs to flow to elk.. and linking the Jenkins container to the elk one via `--link` gets some generic events into the elk stack.

But want I really want is the Jenkins container to (via the [Jenkins Notification plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin)) to log builds into elk  no matter what I try tcp or http the the port I use on the docker host nothing shows up.

On the host the port 3333 is input to the elk container (`3333` is the port for logstash).

From the docker host I can just do something like `"echo "hello new World" | nc localhost 3333"` and elk picks it up.

I am starting elk first with this:

```
docker run -d --name elk-docker -p 8686:80 -p 3333:3333 -p 9200:9200 elk-docker
```

Then Jenkins with this:

```
docker run -p 8585:8080 -v $PWD/docker/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/lib/jenkins -t jenkins-docker
```

I have also tried this linking the two with no success.

```
docker run -p 8585:8080 --link elk-docker:elk -v $PWD/docker/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/lib/jenkins -t jenkins-docker
```

In Jenkins I have the job notifiers plug-in installed and I was trying to use a simple TCP to port 333 and get the main events of the Jenkins job showing up in Elk by using the URL `172.17.0.5:3333`. `172.17.0.5` is the IP of the logstash container.

Comment: can you edit your question and show the docker run commands for the two containers?

Comment: What method are you using to get container logs to ELK from the host?

Comment: please show the real docker image for others to reproduce,  `elk-docker`  doesn't exist. if you use `--link`, you can use `elk` hostname in URL. It is simple jenkins notification plugin & logstash issues.